# How to write unit test of Vertical (vert.x application) using mockito and junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, vert.x

How can I write unit test for verticals which are being used for sending and receiving messages via channels. I need to mock channel messages and wanted to assert true/false with mocked messages. I need to use junit, mockito. Here is Documentation for vertx unit test. http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/
Can someone help me to write sample unit test for below vertical code?
In this case EventBusReceiverVerticle has been deployed and I wanted to mock message on channel "anAddress" so that I can assert if it is same from both side (i.e from sender and receiver side). Thanks in Advance

```
 public class EventBusReceiverVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override                       
  public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
    super.start(startFuture);
    vertx.eventBus().consumer("anAddress", message -> vertx.<String> executeBlocking(future -> {
        System.out.println("received message.body() = "+ message.body());
        future.complete("success");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your snippet looks wrong. You will complete the `startFuture` anytime a message is received. Besides you don't need `executeBlocking` here. Why do you want to mock the message if the body is just a `java.lang.String` ?

Comment: This is not complete code, Actually on channel "anAddress" I am sending and receiving json body via two Vertical. But not able to find a way to write unit test for
1- Mock sender message so that I can assert with receiver side
2- How to write unit test for sender side
3- How to assert messages for both sender and receiver side
4- How to mock local db if vertical sending data from local db
Can you help me how to write unit test for above snippet ??